# How to pass a linux directory path to a function

Tags: r

I checked similar threads and tried accordingly, but still facing issue.

My function:

```
pollutantmean("/root/specdata","","")
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {

    ## Get a list of filenames
    filenames <- list.files(path=directory, pattern="*.csv")

    ## Initialize a vector to hold values
    vals <- vector()

    ## Loop over the passed id's
    for(i in id) {

        ## Pad the i to create a filename
        filename <- sprintf("%03d.csv", i)
        filepath <- paste(directory, filename, sep="/")

        ## Load the data
        data <- read.csv(filepath)

        ## Select our column
        d <- data[,pollutant]

        ## Ignore NAs
        d <- d[!is.na(d)]

        ## append to our vector
        vals <- c(vals, d)
    }

    ## Return the value rounded to 3 dec places
    round(mean(vals), 3)
}
```

error:

```
pollutantmean <- function("/root/specdata", "nitrate", id = 1:332) {
## Error: unexpected string constant in "pollutantmean <- function("/root/specdata""
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Have you got an errant quote somewhere?

Comment: @Hugh: can you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: So my guess is that (somewhere) you put a quote `"` before typing `pollutantmean`. But it's difficult to tell. Can you put the exact command(s) you made that brought up this error?

Comment: Er, do you need to put `pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {` on a separate line??

Comment: @Hugh: I have not much idea. What I believe that I have to pass parameters to function from different function call, like we do in other lang. That is why one is Fn call and other is Fn definition in above code

Comment: Please don't edit this to add the coursera tag: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274845/burninate-and-blacklist-the-coursera-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following function. It works well:

```
dirfn = function(dirname){
    print(getwd())
    setwd(dirname)
    print(getwd())
}
```

Comment: tried it, executing above code directly does not give any result, while passing `dirfn("\root")` give error `dirfn("\root")
Error: could not find function "dirfn"`

Comment: Did you paste above function first on R command prompt. There the function should be found. You may not be able to cd to /root if you do not have enough permission to go to that directory. Try creating and 'temp' folder in your home folder (command 'mkdir temp' on linux terminal prompt) and then give command on R prompt: dirfn('temp').

Comment: Also in linux path is with slash and not backslash: try '/root'

Comment: thanks dear,I am using R studio and above program is in .r file

Comment: now that error went, but after runnig I got this `> round(mean(vals), 3)
[1] NaN`

Comment: `head(vals); str(vals)
logical(0)
 logi(0) ` thanks for showing efforts

Comment: I think at this stage you have got answer to your original question, so you should accept an answer and post another question regarding your new problem. There is an extended discussion warning coming.